# Sendgrid php send to multiple recipients

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have simple sendgrid php script to send email, only issue here is that i need to add more recipients, so this code works only for one recipient, i was looking at official documentation but was unable to find any useful info, is there anyone who knows how and what i need to change here to add more recipients/emails.

```
function sendEmail($subject, $to, $message) {
    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "sample@email.com");
    $subject = $subject;

    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $to);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", $message);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    $apiKey = 'MY_KEY';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    echo $response->statusCode();
}
```

Comment: Call the function for each email address.

Comment: Code sample please ?

Comment: really? loop through your addresses and call the function.

Comment: So you end up with 100 requests instead of one. Very clever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SendGrid\Mail` class supports adding multiple `to` addresses through the `SendGrid\Personalization` class.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L31-L35

Think of a `Personalization` as the envelope for your email. It holds the recipient's addresses and other similar data. Each `Sendgrid\Mail` object, must have at least one `Personalization`.

Through the constructor you are using, a `Personalization` object is already created for you, see here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php#L951-L958

You can create a `Mail` object [without this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L24) and later [add your own](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L52) `Personalization`.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, this is how I have managed to do this and it's working good.

```
function sendEmail($subject, $to, $message, $cc)
{
    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "sample@email.com");
    $subject = $subject;

    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $to);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", $message);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    foreach ($cc as $value) {
        $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $value);
        $mail->personalization[0]->addCC($to);
    }

    $apiKey = 'MY_KEY';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    echo $response->statusCode();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still looking for an answer to how to **add multiple emails** in **To, Cc, and Bcc**, Using **SendGrid**, here is what helped me.

First, you need to add an associative array like this:
for multiple emails in **to** (recipients):

```
$tos = [
"example1@example.com" => "User 1", 
"example1@example.com" => "User 2"
];
```

and in your `SendMail` class use this `$email->addTos($tos);` instead of `$email->addTo;`

**Similarly**, for multiple **Cc** use

```
$email->addCcs($cc);
```

and for **Bcc**

```
$email->addBccs($bcc);
```

Here is the link to see more details [sendgrid php](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#send-an-email-to-a-single-recipient)

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeEmail($to_emails = array(),$from_email,$subject,$body) {
    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $from_email);

    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $to_emails[0]);
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $body);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $to_emails[1]);
    $mail->personalization[0]->addTo($to);

    return $mail;
}

function sendMail($to = array(),$from,$subject,$body) {

    $apiKey = 'your api key';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
    $request_body = makeEmail($to ,$from,$subject,$body);
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
    echo $response->statusCode();
    echo $response->body();
    print_r($response->headers());
}

$to = array('test1@example.com','test2@example.com');
$from = 'from@example.com';
$subject = "Test Email Subject";
$body = "Send Multiple Person";

sendMail($to ,$from,$subject,$body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now Sendgrid provides an easy way for sending single mail to multiple recipients,

it provides **`Mail::addTos` method in which we can add multiple mails to whom we want to send our mail**,

we **have to pass associative array of user emails and user names** into `addTos`.

see below example:

```
$tos = [ 
        //user emails       =>  user names  
        "user1@example.com" => "Example User1",
        "user2@example.com" => "Example User2",
        "user3@example.com" => "Example User3"
    ];
    $email->addTos($tos);
```

If you want to see Full example which is provided in sendgrid-php github library then i have included it below, so you can understand the whole example:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // If you're using Composer (recommended)
// Comment out the above line if not using Composer
// require("<PATH TO>/sendgrid-php.php");
// If not using Composer, uncomment the above line and
// download sendgrid-php.zip from the latest release here,
// replacing <PATH TO> with the path to the sendgrid-php.php file,
// which is included in the download:
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/releases

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$tos = [ 
    "test+test1@example.com" => "Example User1",
    "test+test2@example.com" => "Example User2",
    "test+test3@example.com" => "Example User3"
];
$email->addTos($tos);
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
}
```

Ref:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#send-an-email-to-multiple-recipients